# Как прописать PATH в Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, latex

Скачал [texlive 15](http://www.tug.org/texlive/), в конце установщик попросил сделать это:

1. Добавьте `/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/doc/man` в `MANPATH`.
2. Добавьте `/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/doc/info` в `INFOPATH`.
3. И самое главное, добавьте `/usr/local/texlive/2015/bin/i386-linux`
   в ваш `PATH` для текущей и будущих сессий.

Как это сделать?

Comment: кстати, во всех популярных дистрибутивах есть пакет `texlive`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Довольно простой способ прописать что-то в `PATH` -- это открыть файл `.bashrc` (или `.zshrc`, или файл для другой используемой оболочки), лежащий в домашнем каталоге (`~/.bashrc`), и дописать в конце:

```
# add texlive to PATH
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/texlive/2015/bin/i386-linux
export INFOPATH=$INFOPATH:/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/doc/info
export MANPATH=$MANPATH:/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/doc/man
```

Для того, чтобы действия вступили в силу, можно либо перезапустить терминал, либо ввести

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

---

**Пояснение:**

Синтаксис

```
export VAR=$VAR:path
```

используется для *добавления* нового пути в переменную. Символ `:` является символом разделения путей в linux. Если бы требовалось только создать новую переменную, а не добавлять значение к возможно имеющейся, синтаксис был бы проще:

```
export VAR=value
```

Answer (score 4):

> как это сделать?

через двоеточие:

```
export MANPATH=/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/doc/man:$MANPATH
export INFOPATH=/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/doc/info:$INFOPATH
export PATH=/usr/local/texlive/2015/bin/i386-linux:$PATH
```

чтобы не выполнять эти команды вручную в каждом экземпляре *shell*-а, можно добавить их в конец конфигурационного файла вашего *shell*-а, который называется `~/.имяrc`. узнать имя *shell*-а можно так:

```
$ echo $SHELL
/bin/bash
```

значит, файл, в который можно добавить команды: `~/.bashrc`.