# Не запускаются python команды

Tags: python, bash, unix, macos

Переустановил python зачем-то и команды (pytest, django-admin, celery, ...)  пакетов из профиля перестали запускаться.
Помогает когда запускаю: `$ export PATH=$PATH:/Users/where/Library/Python/3.5/bin/`

Но как это нормально исправить, без костылей?

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/456960/178576

Comment: очень интересно как раньше без этого работало

Comment: вероятно потому, что программа *python* находилась в одном из каталогов, перечисленных в переменной окружения `PATH`.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как прописать PATH в Ubuntu?](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/456956/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-path-%d0%b2-ubuntu)

Answer (score 0):

```
$ echo 'PATH=$PATH:/Users/where/Library/Python/3.5/bin/'>>~/.bashrc 
$ source ~/.bashrc
```

И все. `export` не нужен, тк переменная `PATH` уже экспортированна