# Установка Laravel через Composer

Tags: linux, laravel, composer

Устанавливаю Laravel через Composer, дошел до этапа:

....Проверьте, чтобы директория $HOME/.composer/vendor/bin (или аналогичная в зависимости от вашей ОС) находилась в переменной $PATH, что позволит вашей системе найти и выполнить команду laravel...

Что конкретно нужно сделать?

Linux Mint (Ubuntu 4.8)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`echo $PATH`

Если нужного пути нет, то добавьте его. Вот тут, например, написано как это можно сделать: [Как прописать PATH в Ubuntu?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/456956/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-path-%D0%B2-ubuntu)

У себя (Laravel Homestead) в самый конец файла `.profile` добавил `PATH="$HOME/.composer/vendor/bin:$PATH"`